# How can a Function be a Superposition of Infinite Functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

In learning about Fourier series, they were presented to me (informally) as a way to 'break down' a function into a series of discrete 'constituent' functions. This makes perfect sense to me. However, in a Fourier transform, they seem to be broken down into an infinite number of functions - my question is, how is this possible? In summing this infinite number of constituent functions (to synthesize the original function), won't you end up with something that has infinite amplitude?

Comment: What is the sum of $\sum_{i > 0} 2^{-i}$?

Comment: Perhaps I should've rephrased my question - I understand that it may be composed of an infinite number of **discrete** functions (so a countably infinite number). However, I'm more confused as to how there can be an **uncountable infinity** of constituent functions.

Comment: Fair enough, but the main idea is that convergence of series and integrals occurs when the terms that are accumulated decay fast enough.  And this is true in both the countable and uncountable cases.  Not all functions have Fourier transforms, because the integral does not always converge.  A simple *sufficient* condition that is used in practice is that the Fourier transform exists for functions that are absolutely integrable and of bounded variation.

Comment: Really, there is no such thing as an infinite sum. The so-called infinite sums are limits of finite sums. Without a topology or some other notion of closeness, such things cannot be defined.

Answer (score 4):

The heuristic short answer is that the integral used in the Fourier transform assigns infinitesimally small weight to each of the functions added up (just as we imagine an integral as an infinite sum of infinitesimal strips that add up to a finite area).

One possible longer answer is that one sees this occur when we try to "derive" the Fourier transform from Fourier series. Recall that if $f$ is a (sufficiently nice) complex-valued function that is periodic on an interval of length $L$, we can take the Fourier coefficients for $f$ as
$$ f_k = \int_{-L/2}^{L/2} e^{-2\pi i k x/L} f(x) \, dx, $$
and then Fourier's Theorem states
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{L}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f_k e^{2\pi i kx/L}. $$
My impression is you're happy with this idea, although the normalisation of the coefficients I chose looks a bit strange at the moment.

Now, we want to see what happens if we let $f$ have longer and longer period. We first make a notational adjustment: let $\omega=k/L$, and let $\tilde{f}(\omega) = \tilde{f}(k/L) = f_k $. At the moment $\tilde{f}(\omega)$ is a function a discrete set of values, but the distance between neighbouring elements of this set is $1/L$, so it gets smaller and smaller. So now we have
$$ \tilde{f}(\omega) = \int_{-L/2}^{L/2} e^{-2\pi i\omega x} f(x) \, dx. $$
No drama here: taking $L \to \infty$ just turns this into $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2\pi i\omega x} f(x) \, dx $, which is of course the Fourier transform. Conceptually, this isn't any different from the Fourier series integral: it's just that we have a different variable. On the other hand, the other equation has become
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{L}\sum_{\omega L=-\infty}^{\infty} \tilde{f}(\omega) e^{2\pi i \omega x} = \frac{1}{L}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \tilde{f}\left(\frac{k}{L}\right) e^{2\pi i k x/L}. $$
Ah, but this is a Riemann sum! As $L \to \infty$, it tends to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2\pi i \omega x}\tilde{f}(\omega)  d\omega $, which is of course the inverse Fourier integral. (Handling the infinite interval here is a bit tricky, but this makes total sense if $\tilde{f}(\omega)$ was only nonzero on a finite interval, where we would see a normal sort of finite Riemann sum apply.)

The moral of the story is that the $1/L$ in the Fourier sum formula turns out to be vital in decreasing the weight of each term in the series in just the right way to turn it into the Riemann sum of an integral, and this is one not-particularly-rigorous way of deriving the form of the inverse Fourier integral.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! Just to clarify - when you start taking the limit of L to infinity, you're 'stretching' the bounds so that the function does not have to periodic?

Comment: Yes, $f$ eventually has such a long period that you can't tell it's periodic. It's helpful to remember that long period $\implies$ closely spaced possible frequencies: it's the same as the rule that scaling $x$ leads to the inverse scaling in $\omega$.

Comment: After thinking on this a while, it seemed to me that the Fourier transform of a function is analogous to a continuous probability distribution (i.e. does it mean anything to say that $F(\omega) = 3$ other than to compare it to the value of F at another location?), while a Fourier series is like a discrete probability distribution. Is this correct?

Comment: This may or may not help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)

Comment: I wasn't quite able to understand it (I haven't studied too much probability in depth), but what I took from it is that the Fourier transform of a density function somewhat reveals the 'identity' of that function? Does this imply that how I thought of the transform function is correct?

Comment: Both Fourier series and integrals work best when talking about "convergence in mean square" (i.e $f_n \to f$ if $\int \lvert f - f_n \rvert^2 \to 0$). This is much weaker than uniform (or even pointwise) convergence in general, which is what you need when talking about specific values of a function. Remember that even a discrete Fourier series does not necessarily sum to the value of the $f$ at a given point (if $f$ is discontinuous, and the series converges, it takes the average of the points on both sides).